# JSONPath to list all nodes in ready state except the ones which are tainted?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to list all nodes which are in ready state except the ones which have any kind of taint on them. How can I achieve this using jsonpath ?

I tried below statement taken from k8s doc but it doesn't print what I want. I am looking for output such as --  `node01 node02`. There is no master node in the output as it has a taint on it. What kind of taint is not really significant here.

```
JSONPATH='{range .items[*]}{@.metadata.name}:{range @.status.conditions[*]}{@.type}={@.status};{end}{end}' \
 && kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath="$JSONPATH" | grep "Ready=True"
```

Comment: Are you able to use `python` or `jq`, which can be a ton easier to reason about, or is your situation that you **must** use `jsonpath`? Even using `go-template=` may be easier to reason about, but I'm not 100% certain about that

Comment: I think I can use jq.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have successfully listed my nodes that are `ready` and `not tainted` using `jq`.

Here you have all the nodes:

```
$ kubectl get nodes

gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-9c101360-9lvw   Ready    <none>   31s   v1.13.11-gke.9
gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-9c101360-fdhr   Ready    <none>   30s   v1.13.11-gke.9
gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-9c101360-gq9c   Ready    <none>   31s   v1.13.11-gke.
```

Here I have tainted one node:

```
$ kubectl taint node gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-9c101360-9lvw key=value:NoSchedule

node/gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-9c101360-9lvw tainted
```

And finally a command that list the `not tainted` and `ready` nodes:

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o json | jq -r '.items[] | select(.spec.taints|not) | select(.status.conditions[].reason=="KubeletReady" and .status.conditions[].status=="True") | .metadata.name'

gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-9c101360-fdhr
gke-standard-cluster-1-default-pool-9c101360-gq9c
```

Comment: Totally worked. Thanks. Can you please point me to some good practice questions out there with such twisted scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it using `-o jsonpath` and `awk`

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME           STATUS                     ROLES    AGE   VERSION
controlplane   Ready                      master   27m   v1.19.0
node01         Ready,SchedulingDisabled   <none>   26m   v1.19.0
node02         Ready                      <none>   26m   v1.19.0
node03         Ready                      <none>   26m   v1.19.0
```

`controlplane` and `node01` are ready but have taints `NoSchedule`

To list all the `nodes` with name, status `Ready=True` and `taints`

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]} {.metadata.name} {" "} {.status.conditions[?(@.type=="Ready")].status} {" "} {.spec.taints} {"\n"} {end}' 
 controlplane   True   [{"effect":"NoSchedule","key":"node-role.kubernetes.io/master"}] 
  node01        True   [{"effect":"NoSchedule","key":"node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable","timeAdded":"2021-04-03T12:22:56Z"}] 
  node02        True    
  node03        True
```

Using `awk` to print the `Ready Nodes` and do not have `taints` `NoSchedule`

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]} {.metadata.name} {" "} {.status.conditions[?(@.type=="Ready"].status} {" "} {.spec.taints} {"\n"} {end}'  | awk '$2=="True"' | awk '$3  !~/"NoSchedule"/ { print $1}'
node02
node03
```